# Installing python-nmap package on Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, installation, nmap

I am trying to install `nmap` package on my mac. After I had completed the installation process described on the [developer's site](http://xael.org/norman/python/python-nmap/) I tried to run the following code:

```
import nmap
def nmapScan(tgtHost, tgtPort):
    nmScan = nmap.PortScanner()
```

So I got an error:

```
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/nmap/nmap.py", line 180, in __init__
nmap.nmap.PortScannerError: 'nmap program was not found in path. PATH is :/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin'
```

Ok. I found the path to `python-nmap` package and added it manually to the `PATH`. I believe that I have to add one that contains `nmap.py` file. Here it is:

```
/Users/%username%/Documents/Python_docs/python-nmap-0.1.4/nmap
```

*And I am still getting the same error. Does anyone know why*? Is there someone else who had this problem before? I have searched through internet and there is nothing that helps me. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the nmap first. Use this link [nmap](http://nmap.org/dist/nmap-6.47.dmg). Since the Python library invokes the nmap binary. nmap binary should be available in your system.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was kinda confused by the fact that this is a software distributed by other guys. Fortunately, MacPorts has this package and it is easy to install.
Sorry, I cannot vote up, I gotta have higher reputation. But your answer works!

Answer (score 0):

Install nmap with homebrew and this error goes away.

```
brew install nmap
```

You can do this before or after you install `python-nmap`.